# Got a value from a list and want to get the id of the item having the list as property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

my problem is:

```
public ActionResult DeleteImage(string imagepath)
{
    int tourid = db.Tours.Where(x => x.Images.Where(y => y.Path == imagepath));

...
```

I got tours with a list of images. Images have paths. My controller knows the path of the file but I need the id of the tour. With a foreach its easy, but i would like to solve the problem with linq.

Thanks
Edit:
A Foreach solution:

```
int tourid;
foreach (var tour in db.Tours.ToList())
{
    foreach (var image in tour.Images)
    {
        if (image.Path == imagepath)
        {
            tourid = tour.TourID;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FirstOrDefault` or `First` and `Any`

```
int tourId = db.Tours.First(tour => tour.Images.Any(img => img.Path == imagepath)).Id;
```

This will throw an exception if the tour doesn't exist.
The following will not

```
int tourId = -1;
var tour = db.Tours.
    FirstOrDefault(tour => tour.Images.Any(img => img.Path == imagepath));

if (tour != null)
{
    tourId = tour.Id;
}
```

This basically translates to
"In tours, find the `First` where `Any` of the image's `Path` equals `imagepath`"

There are plenty of tutorials on `Linq`. I suggest you look into them!

Comment: Nice, seems to work. Thx. And could you tell me how to post code blocks here? Seems I am too stupid to make code blocks here.

Comment: Fantastic! Please mark as answer! Code blocks? Use four spaces. And write the code after, or just highlight the code in the editor and click the `{ }` icon.
I suggest you take a look at this link as well:
http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Thanks. I dont post that often here. But now I know how to post code correctly ;) And the tutorials dont help. I switched from java to c#. You are using resharper?

Comment: We all learn differently I suppose. Part of learning is _not understanding_, remember that. I do not use ReSharper currently.

Comment: I am not a senior and have still to learn a lot. I am more in the client-side. Working with linq since about 3 years. But you are right, we learn differently. And it seems I am learning a bit slow the linq-stuff ;)